# Statistical simulation

Tags: c, bash, simulation, statistics

I've written the following program as a submission to the German Federal Computer Science Competition for highschool students. The program makes the following simulation with a given number of days and a given *α*. In order to simplify my code, I use a shellscript to run multiple simulations in parallel. You can get all of the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/fuzxxl/bwinf2012):  (in directory 5).

I know that my implement correctly the fact that the happiness is calculated *once a day*. I calculate it just when needed.

### Question

(Translated from German, see [source](http://www.bundeswettbewerb-informatik.de/fileadmin/templates/bwinf/aufgaben/bwinf31/Aufgabenblatt311_simple.pdf))

> The CEO of Nash Ltd. wants to see her workers happy. Thus, she likes
>   to provide them with free coffee. [...] After a period of ten days
>   where the CEO's assistant makes coffee, the workers have to make
>   coffee on their own. Every evening, the remaining coffee is poured
>   away.
>
> The carafe can contain up to ten cups of coffee, there are 15 workers.
>   Each worker likes to drink three cups a day, one in the morning (8 to
>   10 AM), one at noon (12 to 2 PM) and one in the afternoon (3 to 5 PM).
>   I each of these timeslots the workers arrive in a random order and
>   behave like this:
>
> If there is coffee left in the carafe they pour one cup and leave. If
>   the carafe is empty, the behavior depends on whether they are happy or
>   not. If they are, they brew a new carafe and take one cup. If not, the
>   leave in anger without drinking any coffee.
>
> Whether a worker is happy on a certain day is decided right after they
>   get up. It depends on how often they drank coffee in the last ten days
>   and on how often they brew coffee in that time. The exact definition
>   reads:
>
> If a person drank *n* cups in the last ten days and brew coffee for
>   *m* times, he or she is happy iff  *n* >= 10 and *m/n* < *α*; *α* is a personal threshold.
>
> Write a program that simulates the worker where *α* is equal for all
>   of them. How many cups of coffee is a worker drinking on the long-term
>   average every day depending on *α*?

### stats.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define STAT_DAYS    10 /* days in statistical window */
#define INTRO_DAYS   10 /* Amount of days the assistant refills the can */
#define WORKER_COUNT 15 /* number of worker in the company */
#define CAN_CAPACITY 10 /* Cups per can */
#define SERVINGS      3 /* Coffee servings per worker per day */

/* data for one worker */
typedef struct {
    int cups;
    int cans;
} worker_t[STAT_DAYS];

/* data for the whole company at a given point */
typedef struct {
    double threshold;
    int day_number;
    int total_cups; /* total number of cups drunk by the workers */
    int can_state;
    worker_t workers[WORKER_COUNT];
} company_t;

/* xorshift random number generator for random number generation with good
 * statistical properties. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift */
static uint32_t xor_state[4], xor_now;
static int xor_entropy = 0;

static uint32_t xor128(int bits) {
    uint32_t t;

    /* use remaining entropy if possible */
    if (xor_entropy < bits) {
        xor_entropy = 32;
        t = xor_state[0] ^ (xor_state[1] << 11);
        xor_state[0] = xor_state[1];
        xor_state[1] = xor_state[2];
        xor_state[2] = xor_state[3];
        xor_state[3] ^= (xor_state[3] >> 19) ^ (t ^ ( t >> 8));
        xor_now = xor_state[3];
    }

    xor_entropy -= bits;
    t = xor_now & ((1<<bits)-1);
    xor_now >>= bits;
    return t;
}

/* initialize the random number generator. Return 0 on success. */
static uint32_t init_xor128(void) {
    FILE *entropy = fopen("/dev/urandom","rb");
    size_t items_read;

    if (entropy == NULL) {
        perror("Can't open /dev/random");
        return 1;
    }

    setbuf(entropy,NULL); /* We don't need any buffering */

    items_read = fread(xor_state,sizeof xor_state[0],4,entropy);

    fclose(entropy);

    if (items_read != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't initialize rng.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

/* number of bits used by i. __builtin_clz is an intrisic available on gcc
 * and clang. */
static int bits(uint32_t i) {
    return 32 - __builtin_clz(i);
}

/* Generate a permuted array of pointers to members of an array of workers.
 * Algorithm taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle */
static void shuffle_array(int out[WORKER_COUNT]) {
    int i,j;

    out[0] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
        /* get random numbers till you get one in range */
        while (j = xor128(bits(i)), j > i);
        out[i] = out[j];
        out[j] = i;
    }
}

/* Is a worker happy? */
static bool happy(worker_t *worker,double threshold) {
    int i;
    int cup_count = 0, can_count = 0;

    /* get amount of cups drunk, cans brewed */
    for (i = 0; i < STAT_DAYS; i++) cup_count += (*worker)[i].cups;
    for (i = 0; i < STAT_DAYS; i++) can_count += (*worker)[i].cans;

    /* I interprete n >= 10 as "n >= sliding window" */
    return cup_count >= STAT_DAYS && 1.0L*can_count/cup_count < threshold;
}

/* simulate one round of coffee for all workers */
static void coffee_round(company_t *company) {
    int order[WORKER_COUNT];
    int i, day_mod = company->day_number % STAT_DAYS;

    shuffle_array(order);

    for (i = 0; i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
        int j = order[i];
        if (!company->can_state && company->day_number >= INTRO_DAYS) {
            if (!happy(&company->workers[j],company->threshold)) continue;

            company->can_state = CAN_CAPACITY - 1;
            company->workers[j][day_mod].cans++;
        }

        company->can_state--;
        company->workers[j][day_mod].cups++;
        company->total_cups++;
    }
}

/* simulate one day of coffee */
static void day(company_t *company) {
    /* day_mod: index into the statistical tables */
    int i, day_mod = company->day_number % STAT_DAYS;

    /* zero out statistics entry for today */
    for (i = 0;i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
        company->workers[i][day_mod].cups = 0;
        company->workers[i][day_mod].cans = 0;
    }

    company->can_state = 0; /* empty can */

    for (i = 0;i < SERVINGS; i++) coffee_round(company);

    company->day_number++; /* A day has passed */
}

/* Main function */
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    company_t *company;
    int day_count;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s days threshold\n",argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* allocate and set to zero */
    company = calloc(sizeof *company,1);

    if (!sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&day_count) || day_count <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s is not a valid number of days.\n",argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!sscanf(argv[2],"%lf",&company->threshold)) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s is not a valid threshold.\n",argv[2]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (init_xor128()) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (company->day_number < day_count) day(company);

    /* print output */
    printf("%.6lf\t%.6lf\n",
      company->threshold,
      ((double)company->total_cups/day_count)/WORKER_COUNT);

    free(company);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### stats.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#shell script for statistics creation. This shell script generates a table of
#statistics for a lot of happiness thresholds and saves them into happiness.csv

#various parameters
STATFILE=stats.tsv
SIM=./stats
JOBS=$(grep -ic ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) #number of processors available

#search space
START=0.0
STEP=0.0016
END=0.5
DAYS=$((1024*1024))

LC_NUMERIC=C #set numeric locale to C in order to get correct separators
LC_COLLATE=C #set collating sequence to C in order to sort correctly
#calculate results in parallel
seq $START $STEP $END | xargs -n 1 -P $JOBS $SIM $DAYS >$STATFILE
sort -o $STATFILE $STATFILE #sort output as it might be unordered
```

### Makefile

```
CFLAGS ?= -O3 -Wall
XELATEX ?= xelatex
GNUPLOT ?= gnuplot
PYGMENTIZE ?= pygmentize
PYGMENTIZE_STYLE ?= borland
PYGMENTIZE_OPTS ?= -O linenos

5.pdf: 5.tex plot.tex stats.tex definitions.tex
    $(RM) *.aux
    $(XELATEX) -halt-on-error $< >/dev/null
    $(XELATEX) -halt-on-error $< >/dev/null

definitions.tex:
    $(PYGMENTIZE) -f tex -S $(PYGMENTIZE_STYLE) > $@

.c.tex:
    $(PYGMENTIZE) $(PYGMENTIZE_OPTS) -o $@ $<

plot.tex: stats.gp stats.tsv
    $(GNUPLOT) $<

stats.tsv: stats
    ./stats.sh

clean:
    $(RM) *.pdf *.aux *.log definitions.tex stats.tex plot.tex *.tsv stats *.eps

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 8):

Overall, this is very clean and I have only a few small improvements.

1) In `happy`:

```
/* get amount of cups drunk, cans brewed */
for (i = 0; i < STAT_DAYS; i++) cup_count += (*worker)[i].cups;
for (i = 0; i < STAT_DAYS; i++) can_count += (*worker)[i].cans;
```

could be a single for loop.

2) In `day` (by the way, this should probably be `simulate_day` or something):

```
for (i = 0;i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
    company->workers[i][day_mod].cups = 0;
    company->workers[i][day_mod].cans = 0;
}
```

could be

```
for (i = 0; i < WORKER_COUNT; i++) {
    company->workers[i][day_mod] = {
        .cups = 0,
        .cans = 0;
    }
}
```

3) In `main`, you calloc and free a variable; why not just allocate it on the stack?

4) Comments like

```
/* Main function */
int main(int argc,char **argv) {

/* allocate and set to zero */
company = calloc(sizeof *company,1);

/* print output */
printf("%.6lf\t%.6lf\n",
```

describe *what* the code is doing, not [*why*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/code-tells-you-how-comments-tell-you-why.html) it's doing it.

5) There are a few small style inconsistencies (especially with regards to spaces after commas and semicolons). Consider using [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) and writing an `.astylerc` file for yourself.

Comment: Thank you really much for the feedback! I allocated the structure on the heap as it might be bigger than a few hundred bytes. People always suggest that one should allocate on the heap everything that is not really small.

Comment: Oh. I suppose if `WORKER_COUNT` goes up, that makes sense.